cmake modify a list by adding to each element
Much like: CMake add prefix to each element of a list
I have a list of things (directories, but not always directories) - I need to pass to a custom tool. Generically, for each item in the list I need to insert either "--include" or "--exclude" or "--sometext" in front of each item.
Example:
set( ELIST thisdir thatdir otherdir )
set( ILIST adir bdir cdir )

These need to be passed into a function I create
in that function, I want to expand the passed list into: '--exclude thisdir --exclude thatdir --exclude otherdir' or "-include adir --include bdir --include cdir"
I then pass these on the command line to my custom tool I need to run.
Is there a GENERIC way to do this? Or do I need to do this manually for each thing?
ie: GNU Make has addprefix - I am looking for the same thing

As you could find from that answer to the duplicate question, there is list(TRANSFORM) functionality in CMake. If you find supported "actions" for that command not suitable for your specific needs, then you could easily write your own function/macro.

Note, that while functionality list(TRANSFORM ... PREPEND) is exactly the same as $(addprefix) in Make, CMake distinguishes semicolon-separated lists and white-space separated strings. E.g. in CMake prepending every element in a list with --exclude   and passing this list via  COMMAND to execute_process or add_custom_command gives you a command line like <program> "--exclude thisdir" "--exclude thatdir" "--exclude otherdir", not the one like <program> --exclude thisdir --exclude thatdir --exclude otherdir. If you need the latter, then you need to be more precise in your question.
